# Did they daven after the destruction of the first temple?

Tags: history, tefilla, chutz-laaretz, korban, churban-destruction

I learned that [tefilla was established in place of the korbanos after the destruction of the second temple](http://www.rabbimintz.com/audio/history-of-rabbinic-prayer/). Did any sort of similar thing, meaning standardized prayer service, become instituted after the destruction of the first temple? And if not, why not?

Comment: see also pages 4, 9 http://www.rabbimintz.com/wp-content/uploads/History_of_Rabbinic_Prayer.pdf @DoubleAA i added a link

Comment: My understanding was that synagogues and tefilla existed at the time the second temple still stood.  Correct?

Comment: based on the shiur i linked in the question it would seem they did but in a much less organized way. tefilla as a ritual service certainly doesn't seem to have existed - hence the question

Comment: did Korbanot continue in between the destruction of the first and the establishing of the second temple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to that same shiur they knew they would be rebuilding the beit hamikdash so there was no need to establish a prayer service. it wasn't until the destruction of the second temple where people despaired of rebuilding the temple that they needed to find a "replacement" for korbanot and instituted a set tefilla